# HTML - THYMELEAF - passar parametro

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Criei um parâmetro no ProcedureCallerRepository e no ProcedureCallerRepositoryImpl
até aí tudo ok o meu erro está no html e não sei onde estou errando (me desculpem se for algo bobo porém estou aprendendo ainda)

porém a parte que eu preciso é esta:

```
<form method="GET" th:action="@{/acompanhamentoprimeiropedido}">
    <label>Busca</label>
     <input class="input-sm form-control" type="text" name="parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido" />
```

meu parâmetro é acompanhamentoprimeiropedido e o erro que aparece na tela é : There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido' is not present

alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como passar o parâmetro usando thymeleaf aqui no html?

segue meu código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Acompanhamento Primeiro Pedido


    
        
            
                Data do Pedido: 
                
            
            
                Até 
                
            
        
         
        Busca

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <th:block th:each="diaPedido : ${listaDias}">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-diaPedido" role="tab" th:id="'heading-' + ${diaPedido}">
                        <h4 class="panel-title text-left" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" th:href="'#collapse-' + ${diaPedido}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            <a th:text="${#strings.substring(diaPedido,8,10)+'/'+#strings.substring(diaPedido,5,7)+'/'+#strings.substring(diaPedido,0,4)}"> </a> <i class="fas fa-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div th:id="'collapse-' + ${diaPedido}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" th:attr="aria-labelledby='heading-' + ${diaPedido}">
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <div class="table-responsive display">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr style="font-size: 12px">
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Hora</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Master</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1 hidden-xs">Pedido</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-4">Fantasia</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-2">Contato</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1 hidden-xs">Telefone</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1 hidden-xs">Faturado</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1 hidden-xs">Embarcado</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1 hidden-xs">Previsão</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1">Entrega</th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1"></th>
                                            <th class="text-center col-md-1"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <th:block th:each="primeiroPedido : ${listaPrimeiroPedido}">
                                            <tr th:if="${#strings.replace(primeiroPedido[6],'-','') == #strings.replace(diaPedido,'-','')}">
                                                <td th:text="${#strings.isEmpty(primeiroPedido[6])  ? primeiroPedido[7] : primeiroPedido[7]}"></td>
                                                <td th:text="${primeiroPedido[0]}"></td>
                                                <td class="hidden-xs" th:text="${primeiroPedido[5]}"></td>
                                                <td th:text="${primeiroPedido[2]}"></td>
                                                <td th:text="${primeiroPedido[3]} "></td>
                                                <td class="hidden-xs" th:text="${#strings.replace(primeiroPedido[4],' ','')}"></td>
                                                <td class="hidden-xs" th:text="${#strings.isEmpty(primeiroPedido[8])  ? '' : #dates.format(primeiroPedido[8], 'dd/MM/yyyy')+' '+primeiroPedido[9]} "></td>
                                                <td class="hidden-xs" th:text="${#strings.isEmpty(primeiroPedido[10])  ? '' : #dates.format(primeiroPedido[10], 'dd/MM/yyyy')+' '+primeiroPedido[11]}"></td>
                                                <td class="hidden-xs" th:text="${#dates.format(primeiroPedido[12], 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"></td>
                                                <td th:text="${#strings.isEmpty(primeiroPedido[14])  ? '' : #dates.format(primeiroPedido[13], 'dd/MM')}"></td>
                                                <td class="text-center"><span class="label" th:classappend="${#strings.isEmpty(primeiroPedido[17])  ? 'label-danger' : 'label-success'}"> </span></td>
                                                <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs"> <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" th:attr="data-object-id=${primeiroPedido[5]}" th:onclick="'defineCodigoPrimeiroPedido(\'' + ${primeiroPedido[5]} + '\');'"> </span>
                                                </a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </th:block>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th:block>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--   </form>  -->
    <a class="btn btn-voltar" href="home" role="button botao">Voltar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: O vc quer dizer com parâmetro? O que traz nesta **parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido**?

Comment: @RequestParam String parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido passo isto no meu modelandView  e na lista de objetos da minha procedure

Comment: Joyce gostaria de saber o que quer retornar no Html com este **parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido**, o que traz, um valor?

Comment: LeAndrade obrigada por tentar me ajudar nesse parametro ele passava dados de uma procedure consegui resolver chamando corretamente no html no qual era minha dificuldade deixarei aqui a minha resposta e agradeço a sua atenção!

Answer (score 2):

Deixo aqui a minha resposta :

```
<form method="GET" th:action="@{/acompanhamentoprimeiropedido}">
        <input class="form-control" name="parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 100%;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
</form>
```

o th:action uma classe do thymeleaf tem que ficar dentro do form e acrescentei um button para submeter o name="parametroBuscaPrimeiroPedido".

Dentro deste parâmetro eu chamava dados vindo de uma procedure , no meu caso queria só exibir as informações.